# Dárcula StackOverflow

Tags: novo-recurso

Para nós, que ficamos o dia inteiro no computador, é cansativo demais para a vista.

Eu particularmente, só uso temas escuros nas IDE's.

Seria legal, termos uma opção dessa no SO.

[image: Dárcula]

Comment: Há tantas formas de fazer isso externo ao site, não acredito que haja a minima chance da SE faze algo assim.

Comment: É algo tão simples né... Poderia... assim ficava padrão, sem precisar de extensões, além de ter que fazer em cada máquina que usa...

Comment: Normalmente eu utilizo o modo de leitura que o meu monitor oferece.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr como que é esse negócio de modo leitura ? Nunca ouvi falar

Comment: @RBZ Nos monitores da LG (meu caso), o modo leitura altera as cores/iluminação para evitar o cansaço dos olhos. Na [**review**](http://www.hypeness.com.br/2014/11/hypeness-review-testamos-o-novo-monitor-da-lg-que-vai-aumentar-a-sua-produtividade/) é comentado sobre o recurso. Link Adicional:  https://media.flixcar.com/f360cdn/LG_Electronics-2172619581-BT00001837_648.pdf

Comment: @ValdeirPsr que 10 cara ! Nunca tinha nem ouvido falar ! Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar o [`stylish`](https://userstyles.org/) com o tema [`stackoverflow-dark`](https://userstyles.org/styles/35345/stackoverflow-dark) para deixar os sites da StackExchange com cores negras.

Um exemplo:

[image: sopt_dark_theme]

Comment: Não conhecia isso ! Bacana !

Comment: Eu acho que foste que me mostraste este ai ha uns tempos atrás, que é o que eu uso sempre. Melhor estilo de sempre para o SO :D