# Para quando o tema escuro?

Tags: novo-recurso

Há poucos dias surgiu o tema escuro no [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) principal que eu gosto bastante, e que já esperava há muito. Este tema é naturalmente preferível a soluções que se baseiem no [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/) ou extensões similares para obter um aspeto idêntico.

Vamos ter um tema similar nesta comunidade ? Se sim espera-se que seja para quando ?

Comment: a SE nunca dá previsões exatas sobre os sites internacionais, ou pelo menos nunca de forma clara ou precisa, é provavel que seja logo, já que todas novas funções foram questão de semanas, essa é a mais nova funcionalidade, não deve demorar. Eu não vejo nada que torne o sistema de tema nativo do site preferivel sobre o stylish, as vezes o darkmode nem é bom, então eu crio o meu proprio, ou até crio algo diferente, é gosto pessoal.

Comment: Eu na verdade prefiro o estilo que eles tem no SOen dark aos que haviam no Stylish, sendo que ele é parecido com um do Stylish. Claro que a pessoa pode fazer o próprio mas é preciso perder tempo e ter jeito para fazer algo visualmente apelativo e que seja fácil aos olhos. E ainda tem a situação de ter que instalar em cada PC pois ao que me lembro uma extensão como o Stylish pode ser "automaticamente instalada" com sincronização de browser, mas o estilo tem de ser descarregado localmente.

Comment: Mas aquilo do Stylish foi um exemplo criado, teve gente que fez forks e variações, é isso que é o stylish, vc cria o teu visual e modifica o de outros para o seu gosto.

Comment: Enquanto isso vamos de Dark Reader.

Comment: Alternativa com Stylish: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7069/3635 e https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu sou um dos contribuidores do segundo que você referiu eheheh

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, eu sei ;), foi vc quem me enviou o link a algum tempo atrás, antes mesmo da pergunta, lá no chat estouro de pilha, sempre que possivel eu cito o tema e o stylish, nem sei pq o povo se preocupa com uma futilidade da parte da SO, quando já tem contribuidores como vc que fizeram um tema OTIMO

Comment: Pessoalmente eu posso explicar porque prefiro um nativo ao stylish. Tenho que instalar o stylish em todos os PC's/browsers que uso. Por vezes a extensão fica inativa no chrome e tenho de voltar a ativar. E quando os estilos do SO se alteram os estilos no stylish ficam esquisitos e algumas coisas voltam ao estilo original ficando bem esquisito. Não digo que não é algo bom, mas ainda assim não é equivalente a uma coisa nativa feita pelos criadores do site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Atualização (02/11/2020)

O tema escuro [está disponível no SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8483/112052), por enquanto só no site principal (no meta ainda não).

---

> *Mantive a resposta original abaixo como histórico*.

Segundo [esta resposta no meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351262/401803), talvez tenhamos o *dark mode* "em breve" ([de 6 a 8 semanas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/401803)).

Em tradução livre, a resposta diz:

> *No momento, estamos trabalhando no tema para o Stack Overflow for Teams. Com isso, as comunidades, especialmente as internacionais, terão os benefícios de mudar as variáveis CSS. Isso habilitará o tema escuro.*
>
> *Há um pull request em testes, mas faltando pouco para que esteja pronto para produção.*

---

### Atualização (03/09/2020):

> *This is something we’re interested in doing but will need to solve some things technically before we can set it to [status-planned]. I’ve updated it to [status-deferred] for now.*

Traduzindo:

> *Isso é algo que temos interesse em fazer, mas precisaremos resolver alguns detalhes técnicos antes de considerá-lo [status-aceito](/questions/tagged/status-aceito). Por enquanto ela ficará em [status-futuro](/questions/tagged/status-futuro).*

Ou seja, vai demorar...

Comment: De 6 à 8 semanas?

Comment: @Maniero Bem lembrado, atualizei a resposta :-)

Comment: Achei graça ao meme do tempo, mas é bom saber que efetivamente já estão a trabalhar para trazer o tema

Comment: @Isac Atualizaram a resposta, e infelizmente parece que vai demorar bem mais que as 8 semanas...

Comment: Agradeço o feedkback. Pena que ainda vá demorar mas desde que não seja cancelado já fico contente.

Comment: @Isac Agora sim! https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8483/112052 (atualizei a resposta também)

Comment: Valeu a espera! Obrigado pelo aviso