# Tema escuro agora disponível no Stack Overflow em Português!

Tags: debate

Muito obrigado a [@JNat](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23291/jnat) pela tradução.

---

O que será assim tão difícil em criar um tema escuro para o site? Até [extensões de terceiros](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336626/274323) conseguem tratar do assunto! Mas sempre que pensávamos numa implementação, [ocorria um número enorme de complicações técnicas](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/297). A situação mudou com os [“Stacks styles”](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/) e a migração duma grande parte do site para os usar. Como resultado disso, a primeira vez que começámos a pensar seriamente na possibilidade de suportar um tema escuro foi em Julho de 2019. [No princípio de 2020, o Aaron explorou a possibilidade de termos um tema escuro](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/356) e perto do fim de Março [uma versão beta do tema escuro estava disponível no Stack Overflow em inglês](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/564240).

Estou feliz por anunciar que o modo escuro está, a partir de agora, disponível para todos os usuários logados no Stack Overflow em Português!

[image: Captura de ecrã do tema escuro]

Por agora, o tema escuro está disponível no site principal (no Stack Overflow em todas as línguas). A possibilidade de suportar o tema escuro nos metas (incluindo o Meta Stack Exchange) e outros sites da rede ainda é uma questão em que estamos a pensar.

[Lê mais sobre o tema escuro na publicação do blog do Aaron (em inglês).](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/)

#### Como activar o tema escuro:

Para activar o tema escuro visita o teu perfil no Stack Overflow em Português, vai à secção “Editar perfil e configurações”, daí à secção “Preferências” nas “Configurações do site” e encontrarás a secção “Tema” no topo da página. Aí há três opções — claro, escuro, e “Definição do sistema” que ajustará o tema de acordo com as preferências do teu sistema.

[image: Captura de ecrã da página de preferências, mostrando as três opções: claro, escuro, e definição do sistema.]
(clica na imagem para veres um gif do processo)

#### Como reportar bugs?

Se encontrares um bug, por favor cria uma pergunta no Meta Stack Overflow em Português or Meta Stack Overflow em inglês.

Mal posso esperar por ouvir o vosso feedback!

Comment: Perfeito, **parabéns** a todos pelo trabalho! Coincidência incrível, ontem mesmo eu estava tentando implementar o tema escuro usando o *Stylish*.

Comment: Muito bom! Parabéns aos envolvidos.

Comment: Por que o tema não é aplicadado ao site mobile? Uso muito ele no celular de noite e seria muito melhor se tivesse o tema escuro, seria até mais útil do que ter no desktop. O tema escuro se estenderá ao Meta? Se sim, quando? Se não, por que?